# Why won't my ceiling light turn off with the wall switch disconnected?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I want to install a ceiling light where previously only a box cover existed, no fixture. I connected the black wire to the black fixture wire, white to white, ground to ground. No other wires are present.  I turned the breaker on and the light only stays on. I disconnected the wall switch completely but left the wall wires unconnected (black, white, ground). I think it could be a possible faulty switch. I turned the breaker on and the ceiling light remained on with no switch connection.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have power to switch?  Sometimes switches switch wall outlets.

Comment: Are there any additional wires in the ceiling box?

Comment: there is power to the switch, and there are no additional wires in the ceiling box

Comment: I'm confused... You have 3 wires in the ceiling (fixture) box (black, white, and bare), and 3 wires in the wall (switch) box (black, white, and bare)? There has to be more wires somewhere, otherwise you can't complete the circuit.  Pictures would be very helpful.

Comment: I agree Tester101, there should be more wirew but there are only the 3 in each as you describe in you comment.

Comment: I think now I'll open the circuit breaker panel to see what is going out of the box 3 or 4 wire cable, if only 3 then I wondered if there was a simple  correction that can be made

Comment: If there are only 3 wires in each box, then that switch does not control that light.

Comment: If there are only 3 wires in the switch box and it's live then you have a switch in an outlet box or you measured something wrong. Something is definitely wrong here and sorry but I'm favoring the latter.

Comment: Normally there would be 2 cable ends coming in.  Odd.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're poking around in the wrong hole. The circuit you describe looks something like this...

[image: Circuit]

Which obviously is not possible, since you say the light is on.  More likely, the switch does not control the light at all, and the circuit looks more like this...

[image: Circuits]

It's possible (as previously mentioned) that the switch actually controls a receptacle, or some other device. In which case the ceiling box is probably wired directly to the circuit, and is intended for a fixture with a built-in switch (pull chain).

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely the ceiling box is either not connected to the switch or has been bypassed.  This can happen when the power starts at the light and the switch is remote from it.
There should be a second pair (trio, with ground) of wires coming from the switch.

If not, you have 2 options, run a 2nd wire to a switch or use one of the remote powerline modules, such as X-10.

[image]  [image]  [Leviton HXC10-1TW](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=HXC10-1TW&section=44200)

The Leviton HXC10-1TW is a single address controller that will remotely switch the **[socket rocket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JK23VK)** pictured.  It does require power and neutral, but will work from anywhere in the house (once properly addressed).  The multi point controllers are actually cheaper, but don't give you "in wall", exact replacement look.

NB The SocketRocket is only intended for incandescent bulb use.  CFLs or LED would require a different solution.

Comment: Thanks HerrBag, There are only 2 wires+ gnd at wall,they are hot. Running a new line from ceiling box to room entry wall, might work if I can access it from crawl space. we just bought this house, so not sure if there is crawl space to this room ? A remote sw does give me another option, I suspect house wired incorrectly. thanks Frank